# hdfs file download request url

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

when request download, request url is hostname, so appeared 400 bad request.
my server is 5 and hadoop is 1 namenode, 1 secondary & datanode, 3datanode 
total 1namenode 1secondarynamenode 4datanode

this is my namenode web-ui and request url
http://hadoop04:9864/webhdfs/v1/test/delta-contribs.jar?op=OPEN&namenoderpcaddress=000.000.000.000:9000&offset=0 
when url change instead hadoop04 to hadoop04-ip, then work
[image]

[image]

and this is my xml

## namenode

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>4</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.permissions.enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>/usr/local/hadoop/data/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
        <value>000.000.000.000:50070</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

## secondarynamenode & datanode

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
        <value>000.000.000.000:50090</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir</name>
        <value>/usr/local/hadoop/data/secondarynamenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.http-address</name>
        <value>000.000.000.000:9864</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>/usr/local/hadoop/data/datanode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>4</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

## datanode

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.http-address</name>
        <value>000.000.000.000:9864</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>/usr/local/hadoop/data/datanode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>4</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

## /etc/hosts

```
000.000.000.000 hadoop01
000.000.000.000 hadoop02
000.000.000.000 hadoop03
000.000.000.000 hadoop04
000.000.000.000 hadoop05
```

## workers

```
000.000.000.000(hadoop02)
000.000.000.000(hadoop03)
000.000.000.000(hadoop04)
000.000.000.000(hadoop05)
```

how can i request url change hostname to ip?

Comment: If you search hadoop documentation, there's a setting in core-site.xml or hdfs-site.xml to disable using hostnames

Comment: @OneCricketeer i don`t know option about your comment, but i solved. thank you comment

Comment: Please show your solution below as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
# hdfs-site.xml
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.hostname</name>
    <value>new-datanode-hostname</value>
</property>
```

Write datanode ip on dfs.datanode.hostname value Then will be change datanode`s http address http://hostname:port/ -> http://ip:port/